# How to select some files from a list of files?

Tags: python-2.7, data-extraction

So I am reading through multiple files from different organizations. Every file has file number and organization. I am trying to read through the list of files, only find those ones from the organization `'OCE'`, and ignore others. My goal is to count how many files are from `'OCE'` in total, and print out their file numbers.

My question is how do I code the part that I want to choose only files from `'OCE'` and ignore others? Not even sure which statements to use. Any suggestion is very much appreciated.

```
for filepath in matches[:20]:
    with open (filepath,'rt') as mytext:
        mytext=mytext.read()


        # Find all files from 'OCE'.
        grabOrg=re.findall(r'NSF\s+Org\s+\:\s+(OCE)',mytext)
        if len(grabOrg) != 0:
            OCEOrg=grabOrg[0]   **# Here is my question.**

            from collections import Counter
            countOrg=Counter(OCEOrg)
            print str(OCEOrg) + '|' + countOrg
```

Comment: Doesn't your regex currently only include only those including `"OCE"`? What exactly is the problem with what you currently have?

Comment: So I am having a list of files from different organizations. Each file has the Org info. I want to check through those files and only capture info from files from the organization `'OCE'`, as in `grabOrg=re.findall(r'NSF\s+Org\s+\:\s+(OCE)',mytext)`.

Comment: Yes, that is clear. What is not clear is what the *problem* is; does your code do what you want and if not be specific about what it does instead.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It still prints all `NSF Org` fields out. Those that are not from `OCE` are blank `[ ]`.

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant information - provide a clear description of what you're doing, example inputs and expected and actual outputs